# J2ME - number format

Tags: java-me, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting

I need to format decimal numbers with patterns in J2ME just like java [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

I see an option to port [Format](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules/j2me/java/text/Format.java.htm)/[NumberFormat](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules/j2me/java/text/NumberFormat.java.htm)/[DecimalFormat](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules/j2me/java/text/DecimalFormat.java.htm).

Can you suggest ready to use implementation or library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I've manage to port desktop java implementation: [bbnumberformat](http://code.google.com/p/bbnumberformat/source/browse/#svn/trunk):

```
    String[] patterns = new String[] { "#,#00.00#", "0.0;(0.0)",
            "0.###E0" };
    DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat
            .getNumberInstance();
    double value = -12.321;
    for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
        String pattern = patterns[i];
        format.applyPattern(pattern);
        String text = "Pattern: " + pattern 
        + " Sample: "+format.format(value)+"\n";
        add(new LabelField(text));
    }
```

[alt text http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/6245/9000.jpg](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/6245/9000.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The code below is method that shows how to round a double to n decimals:

```
private double round(double num,int numDecim){
    long p=1;
    //next line – calculate pow(10,brDecim)
    for(int i=0; i<numDecim; i++)p*=10;
    return (double)(int)(p * num + 0.5) / p;
}
```

You may use double `p=1.0;` or `p*=10.0;` instead.