# Java and J2ME calculate ratio

Tags: java, java-me, double, decimal

Hi guys I need some help with calculating and displaying a ratio result.

**so here is the sample code I am working on:**

```
    double a = 11;
    double b = 2508;
    double total1;
    double total2;

    total1 = a / b;

    System.out.println(total1);
```

Now the result I get is 0.0043859649122807015 . However I only need the "0.004" the three decimal places, and to calculate the ratio I will need to round "0.004" in to 1 so how do I do that?

**Phase2**

```
    double a = 11;
    double b = 2508;
    double total1;
    double total2;

    total1 = a / b;

    System.out.println(total1);

    total2 = 1/total1; //1 is equal a rounded 0.004 then devided by 0.004

    System.out.println(total2);
```

But I had to manually put 1 to do the calculation. is there a way to store total 1 from the first calculation? total1 = a/b; . So I can call it back to do a "total2 = "A rounded 1 of 0.004"/total1;

Finally print the result out and is 250.

**Little formula**

```
11/2508 = 0.004

0.004 = 1 

1/0.004= 250

1:250
```

I have tried to use decimalformat on j2me but it does not support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a number formatter

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

```
System.out.format("%.3f%n", pi);     // -->  "3.142"
```

Also just flipwhat your formula.

2508/11 = 228

so 1:228
which is more accurate than 1:250

Comment: J2ME doesn't support formatter, is there anyway go around it?

Comment: String[] patterns = new String[] { "#,#00.00#", "0.0;(0.0)",
            "0.###E0" };
    DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat
            .getNumberInstance();
    double value = -12.321;
    for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
        String pattern = patterns[i];
        format.applyPattern(pattern);
        String text = "Pattern: " + pattern 
        + " Sample: "+format.format(value)+"\n";
        add(new LabelField(text));
    }     from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094700/j2me-number-format

Comment: But im not sure why you are losing accuracy when you can do 2508/11 to give the ratio direct ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Math.round()` and `Math.log10()`.

`log10` determines the location of decimal point, having `log10=0` for `1`.

So, first you calculate decimal point location:

```
Math.log10(total1);
```

this will give

```
-2.357934847000454
```

round it with `Math.round()` which will give

```
-2
```

this is the number you use in calculations.

Final code is

```
    double a = 11;
    double b = 2508;
    double total1;
    double total2;

    total1 = a / b;

    System.out.println(total1);

    // determining point location
    long l = Math.round(Math.log10(total1));

    System.out.println(l);

    // moving point right
    total1 = total1 * Math.pow(10, -l+1);

    System.out.println(total1);

    // rounding
    total1 = Math.round(total1);

    System.out.println(total1);

    // moving point back
    total1 = total1 / Math.pow(10, -l+1);

    System.out.println(total1);

    total2 = 1/total1; //1 is equal a rounded 0.004 then devided by 0.004

    System.out.println(total2);
```

**P.S.**

Also you can learn something from this: [How to convert floats to human-readable fractions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions)